# Accidently deleted all data in the 'master' database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've used this script by accident on the 'master' database instead of a temp database.

```
sp_msforeachtable 'delete from ?'
```

Has it caused any harm? If so, how can I restore the data?

Comment: Restore your most recent backup of the master DB. You have one, right?

Comment: I don't have one. It's a personal development DB with no critical data, so worst that can happen is I have to reinstall SQL Server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it shouldn't have deleted anything (assuming you have no user tables in `master`).

Testing

```
exec sys.sp_MSforeachtable 'select ''?'''
```

Doesn't return anything for me. So it seems to exclude the system tables such as `spt_values`.

Edit: Indeed Looking at the definition of the procedure it does only include tables where `OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N'IsUserTable') = 1`

Comment: Woah!  Thanks! I thought I blew away my database and I was ready to do a reinstall.  This is what happens when you don't check if the database you want is selected the pull down menu in Sql Server Studio.  Why Microsoft? Why couldn't you ask someone to explicity choose a database before opening the query window?  Thank god they put in the IsUserTable condition. Usability is certainly not one of Microsoft's hallmarks.

Comment: Your answer is useful and reassuring, but the `OBJECTPROPERTY` clause is not what saved Stijn from a reinstall. After making the same mistake myself I discovered some interesting things about the procedure's implementation. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12530893/111424) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

Martin Smith is right to say that `sp_MSforeachtable` does not delete system tables.

However, though we may think of tables such as `spt_values` and `MSreplication_options` as system tables, they are in fact user tables according to SQL Server.

When I run this query in my master database:

```
SELECT name, OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, N'IsUserTable') AS IsUserTable
FROM master.sys.tables;
```

I see the following result set:

```
name                  IsUserTable
--------------------- -----------
spt_fallback_db       1
spt_fallback_dev      1
spt_fallback_usg      1
spt_monitor           1
MSreplication_options 1
```

So how was Stijn saved from a reinstall?

If you look at how `sp_MSforeachtable` is implemented, you will see it does something like this to select the tables to drop:

```
declare @mscat nvarchar(12)
select @mscat = ltrim(str(convert(int, 0x0002)))

SELECT *
from dbo.sysobjects o join sys.all_objects syso on o.id = syso.object_id 
where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N'IsUserTable') = 1 and o.category & @mscat = 0;
```

In my master database, this returns an empty result set.

The where clause applies a bitmask to the `category` column of table `sysobjects` to exclude tables that are not '`mscat`'.

So the tables in the master database are protected not because they are system tables, but because they are 'Microsoft' tables.

This use of the category column is completely undocumented in [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) All it has is a vague description:

> Used for publication, constraints, and identity.

But the `sysobjects` table is deprecated anyway, so you shouldn't be using it. :)

An equivalent query using the supported view `sys.tables` would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

In my master database, this also returns an empty result set.